# Joining multiple column with multiple column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to join both deptno and sal same time when comm is not null. I came up with following. But it only accept either deptno or sal. not both in same time.

```
select ename,deptno,sal,comm from emp where deptno,sal in(select sal,deptno from emp where comm is not null);
```

This is a self join.

I am trying  it on oracle 10g

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your purpose is not clear, although it seems you want to write a multi-column semi-join using `IN`. In that case you can simply add parentheses:

```
SELECT ename, deptno, sal, comm 
  FROM emp 
 WHERE (sal, deptno) IN (SELECT sal, deptno FROM emp WHERE comm IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a real join:

```
SELECT e1.ename, e1.deptno, e1.sal, e1.comm
FROM emp e1
JOIN (SELECT distinct sal, deptno
      FROM emp
      WHERE comm IS NOT NULL) e2
ON e1.sal = e2.sal AND e1.deptno = e2.deptno
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldnot your query be like this

```
select ename,deptno,sal,comm from emp where deptno,sal in(select deptno ,sal
from emp where comm is not null);
```

Comment: I think that is what I have written